# Which will be faster in general, tomcat, or straight geoserver?

Tags: performance, tomcat, geoserver

I'm installing a new instance of geoserver (v 2.17.2) and in the install documentation it has the option to install geoserver by itself, or as an applet under tomcat.

Both options look simple enough, but I am wondering if there is any performance benefit by running with tomcat, or if it will run faster without the additional layer.

Has anyone tested these install options to see if there is any performance benefit to either install option?

--
Thanks,
James *"Zeke"* Dehnert

Linux System Administrator
[Aechelon Technologies](https://aechelon.com)
[james.dehnert@aechelon.com](http://mailto:james.dehnert@aechelon.com)

Comment: It is not "by itself" but rather bundled with Jetty.

Comment: also its a servlet not an applet. And if you are really worried the only way to be sure is to try it yourself